# Mute all microphons with one command

Tags: linux-mint, audio, microphone

I am running Linux Mint 19.1 and would like to assign a shortcut key to a script that mutes and unmutes my microphones. I have found many solutions that do this for a single input, e.g.

```
amixer set Capture toggle
pactl set-source-mute $source_number toggle
```

However, as I switch between different inputs (built in mic, bluetooth headset, wired headset), I would prefer something that consistently toggles ALL of these on/off together. This means that they are either all on or all off, no risk of one being on while another is off.
I am unsure weather or not the assigned source numbers in `pactl` are constant or not and would like a solution that will work reliably, independent of if I reconnect the mic 42 times or even connect a different (bluetooth) device.

Is there a command to get the source used by the system (the one that *same as system* refers to in a number of applications, e.g. Zoom)?
If so, when I run the command/script I would like to get the state of that device and set the state of all the relevant devices to the opposite state.

Any suggestions for how I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

Though this does not answer your question, what will work is using

```
pactl set-source-mute @DEFAULT_SOURCE@ toggle
```

To toggle the microphone currently in use or

```
 pactl set-source-mute @DEFAULT_SOURCE@ 1
```

To mute instead of toggle

Answer (score 0):

Using awk you could find and iterate over all inputs:

```
pactl list short sources | awk '/input.*RUNNING/ {system("pactl set-source-mute " $1 " toggle")}'
```

NOTE: If an microphone is connected later and you've already muted some devices, you could end up with your mute state desynced between the different devices.

Comment: It would be possible to make a slight more complex version that tests the current state instead of blindly toggling, but I posted what I had already made for my own use.